# InterSystems Cache Database and SSMS Integration Services Catalogs

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssis, intersystems-cache, ssms-2014

I am trying to built a SSIS package thru BIDS VS 2013. My Datasource is a InterSystems Cache Database, I wanted to Import Tables records from the Datasource to MS SQL Server 2014.

As a Sanity check. I only created one Package to import one Table to MSSQL Server to try out. The connection to the InterSystems Cache Database was successful. The DSN for the InterSystems Cache Database is created in the System for 32 and 64 Bit.

[image]

Here is where my Problem lies. I can successfully execute the SSIS Package in the BIDS Visual Studio 2013 BUT when i deploy the SSIS Package into the Integration Services Catalogs in the SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) i get the following errors:

[image]

I tried so many Options but it just doesnt fix the Problem. It seems that the SSMS Integration Services Catalogs cannot recognize my Datasource BUT why?

Thanks for any tips and help. Thanks a lot in advanced!